# font diaplay half when TextView is too short

Tags: android, textview

the textView's height and width is fixed.

when the length of string is longer than textview,the last-line text sometimes display half.

#### I want,when the last-line text can't display complete,discard it.how to realize?

Comment: Use this in textview xml android:ellipsize="end"

Comment: I don't know how you will be able to discard it, but yes, you can use `Ellipses` to use dots (...) if the text length exceeds the `TextView`'s capacity.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you already have ellipsize enabled, and that's why you're only getting "half" the last line.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you can-

- Remove ellipsize settings and suffer
  the string cut-off.
- Resize your textview so that all the 
  text will fit.
- Change your font size so that all the
  text will fit.

StaticLayout has a way of detecting if the last line will cut off (using getEllipsisCount(line)) which is supposedly used internally by TextView, but I've had no luck using that to detect when a TextView is being cut off ([see post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084647/staticlayout-getellipsiscount-returning-0-when-i-know-its-ellipsizing)).

If this doesn't help, please give us a better picture of what you're doing.